# outputting from a file stuck in loop and not reading?

Tags: c++, file, loops

So the while loop at the bottom of this following code simply just loops continuously I had it working before I added the line

```
questionFile >> answersArray[i];
```

This line seems to break it so that nothing writes into the questionsArray anymore, I'm rather stumped by this so help would be appreciated.

```
ifstream questionFile;
int i = 0;
switch (x){
case 1:
    questionFile.open("Topic1 Questions.txt", ios::app);
    break;
case 2:
    questionFile.open("Topic2 Questions.txt", ios::app);
    break;
case 3:
    questionFile.open("Topic3 Questions.txt", ios::app);
    break;
case 4:
    questionFile.open("Topic4 Questions.txt", ios::app);
    break;
}
if (!questionFile)
{
    cout << "Cannot load file" << endl;
}
else
{
    if (questionFile.peek() != ifstream::traits_type::eof()) {
        while (!questionFile.eof())
        {
            getline(questionFile, questionsArray[i]);
            questionFile >> answersArray[i];
            i++;
        }
    }
    questionFile.close();
}
```

Comment: Try `while (getline(questionFile, questionsArray[i]))`

Comment: nope didn't work left me with a blank console window instead

Answer (score 1):

Both `getline` and `operator>>` extract from the file but `getline` reads until '\n' (or any character you specify) while `operator>>` reads until a whitespace. Furthermore, `operator>>` will leave the '\n' in the stream causes the next invocation of `getline` to read nothing.

Read the [`getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) and [`operator>>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt) documentations for more details (those are links).

Also, post the format that the questions/answers are stored in the file because how your code will run is very dependent on that. If you're just expecting alternating lines of questions and answers, just use `getline` and forget the operator.

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: questions is a string of multiple strings with spaces and answers is just ints, I didn't think to add this sorry about that, I also still can't find a way of fixing this still so any help would be great.

Comment: I forgot to reply to this, do you still need help?

Comment: Nah I finally fixed it by running into a different problem and fixing that.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hard (okay, impossible, really) to be certain what your problem is without seeing things like the type of `answersArray`. It would also help (a lot) to see what a sample of the input file you want to read.

For the moment, I'm assuming your input file look at least a little like this:

```
1) air 2) earth 3) fire 4) water
3
1) Solid 2) Liquid 3) Gas 4) Plasma
2
```

i.e., one line is a string (containing questions or possible answers, or maybe both), and the next line is a single number signifying the correct answer (or something on that order).

Assuming that's the case, I'd read all the data from the input file itself using `std::getline`. Then I'd split that up into the necessary pieces.

I'd probably also create an `answer` class (or something similar) to hold both the string and the number, and overload `operator>>` for that class to read both.

```
struct answer { 
    std::string question;
    int answer;

    friend std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is, answer &a) { 
        std::getline(is, a.question);
        std::string temp;
        std::getline(is, temp);
        a.answer = boost::lexical_cast<int>(temp);
        return is;
    }
};
```

Using that, reading the data from the file could look something like this:

```
std::vector<answer> answers{
    std::istream_iterator<question>(questionFile),
    std::istream_iterator<question>()};
```

This reads the data from the file, and puts the items it reads into the vector I've named `answers`.

While we're at it, I'd also change the code to open the file, at least a little bit. `ios::app` only really makes sense if you're going to write to a file, not just read from it. Second, a case statement to choose hard-coded file names seems a bit clumsy, at least to me.

I'd probably write that part of the code more like this:

```
if (x<0 || x > 4)
    throw std::runtime_error("prohibited file name");

std::stringstream name << "Topic" << x << " Questions.txt";
std::ifstream questionFile(name.str());
```

Comment: bit mind blown by how much you wrote, I'm still a bit stuck on this how ever, answersArray is a filled with ints and questionsArray is filled with a group of strings with spaces, any simple answer would be very appreciated as I am clueless currently